# How to add text apparition on hover image

Tags: image, text, mouseover, jsfiddle, onhover

Hello I would like to know how to have some text apparition on hover when mouse is over images

here is my jfiddle ->

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/h77yuLxk/`
```

thank you guys

Comment: Do you mean like a tooltip?

Comment: yes, exactly @Ding ;)

Answer (score -1):

did you try html alt="text you want here"

Just wondering why you were trying with js.

```
<img src="http://www.500milligrammes.com/juliep/zztestzz/2/index/02/img/mail.png" alt="Email"/>

<img src="http://www.500milligrammes.com/juliep/zztestzz/2/index/02/img/phone.png" alt="Phone"/>


<img src="http://www.500milligrammes.com/juliep/zztestzz/2/index/02/img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />

<img src="http://www.500milligrammes.com/juliep/zztestzz/2/index/02/img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram"/>
```

Comment: Because i would like to have a tooltip, or real text who appear when mousse is over images;)

Comment: http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

these might help